# Auto set cron bash script?

Tags: bash, cron

How to make some script to auto set it's execution based on some time it gets from database or some other way?

Any simple, plain example for that?

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- you have a script what selecting the execution date and the command from the database
- the output format from this script is: [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm `<space>` command_name and_args

For example this will read pairs of "date" "command" from the standard input:

```
while read exectime command
do
    echo "$command" | at -t "$exectime"
done
```

Use it like:

```
/path/to/script_select_from_database | ./the_above_script
```

or this one

```
exectime="$1"
shift
echo "$@" | at -t "$exectime"
```

invoke it"

```
./this_script `/path/to/script_select_from_database`
```

combine both to one script, and/or any other variation...

The scripts queue your commands for the execution with the `at` command. see `man at`.